# New created site collection, is visible in Central Admin, but dont work in the browser, and is not visible in IIS7

Tags: site-collection, site, iis

I am using SharePoint 2013. I have created a new site collection, but it dont work. I dont see it in IIS. But it it is available in Central Admin. I have did a IISreset, but it doesnt work! Someone any idea?

Answer (score 1):

A site collection is a hierarchical group of web sites with one top level site that inherit the same configuration and security.  Each Web application is associated with one application pool . Each Web application can then contain one or more site collections. So An application pool in simple terms is the amount of memory set aside in IIS for one or more Web sites to run in. 
Check in App Pools, Your site collection would be there. Refresh the IIS, CLose it and then again re-open. You will be able to see it.

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Site Collection will not be visible in IIS, only the web application will be visible. Access the site and look in to ULS logs for further information